# The operator != and == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, boolean, key, operator-keyword

I keep getting this error:

> The operator != and == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

on my code and I have no idea on what to do to fix it. Help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

```
public static boolean isPressed(int i)
{
  return (keyState[i] != 0) && (prevKeyState[i] == 0);
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `keyState` and `prevKeyState`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. One of your operands is an `int` while the other is a `boolean`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath public static boolean[] keyState = new boolean[3];           public static boolean[] prevKeyState = new boolean[3];

Comment: @KhelshyMawnik See my answer then; the problem is that you are comparing `boolean`s to `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `keyState[i]` and `prevKeyState[i]` are booleans (true/false values), so it makes no sense to compare them to zero.  Maybe what you want is

```
return (keyState[i] == true) && (prevKeyState[i] == false);
```

or even, in a more readable form

```
return keyState[i]  &&  ! prevKeyState[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
return (keyState[i] == true) && (prevKeyState[i] == false);
```

Because keystate[i] and prevkeystate[i] are of type bool, you must also compare them with a bool.
Alternatively you could write:

```
return keyState[i] && !prevKeyState[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `boolean` with an `int`. Are `keyState` and `prevKeyState` both of type `boolean[]`? If so, this might explain why you are seeing this error.

Simply change your statement to:

```
return (keyState[i] && !prevKeyState[i]);
```

and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you cannot use `!=` to compare a boolean on the left-hand side with an integer (the `0`) on the right-hand side. Judging from the error message, it sounds like `keyState` and `prevKeyState` are both `boolean[]`.

So to fix this, either change your arrays to be `int[]` or test for `keyState[i] != false` instead of `keyState[i] != 0`.

Unlike C, Java has a `boolean` type and you shouldn't use integers like 1 and 0 to stand in for true / false.

Answer (score 0):

just read the error message from the compiler:

keyState and prevKeyState are surely of type: boolean[]

your code must look like this:

```
public static boolean isPressed(int i)
{
  return (keyState[i]) && (! prevKeyState[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've declared boolean arrays boolean[] keyState and boolean[]prevKeyState, but you haven't made that clear here.

If this is true, then you are comparing boolean values keyState[i] and prevKeyState[i] to int values 0 and 1.

try this:

```
return (keyState[i] && !prevKeyState[i]);
```